# React websocket connection closes after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, websocket

I have a websocket server in node and a react client defined as follows:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useParams, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import useWebSocket from 'react-use-websocket';
import Results from './results';
import { WS_URL } from '../constants';

const Submission = () => {

    const location = useLocation();
    const { submissionID } = useParams();
    const [results, setResults] = useState(0)

    const successHeader = "Your submission has been received!";
    const successBody = `This page will update automatically when your results are ready. Bookmark it for reference - results are stored for 24 hours.
     If you provided an email your results will be sent to you upon completion.`
    const failureHeader = "There was a problem processing your submission."
    const failureBody = `Please check that your input is properly formatted and try again. If you continue
    to experience issues with your submission, please contact us.`

    const {
        sendMessage,
        sendJsonMessage,
        lastMessage,
        lastJsonMessage,
        readyState,
        getWebSocket,
    } = useWebSocket(`${WS_URL}/${submissionID}`, {
        share: false,
        filter: () => false,
        onOpen: () => {
            console.log('Opened websocket');
            sendMessage(submissionID)
            return;
        },
        onMessage: (m) => {
            const message = JSON.parse(m.data);
            setResults(message)
            return;
        },
        onClose: () => {
            console.log('Closing')
        },
        heartbeat: {
            message: 'ping',
            returnMessage: 'pong',
            timeout: 60000, // 1 minute, if no response is received, the connection will be closed
            interval: 25000, // every 25 seconds, a ping message will be sent
          },
    });

    return (
        (results !== 0) ? <Results single={false} items={results} /> :
        <Container id='main-content'>
            <h2>{location.state.uploadSuccess ? successHeader : failureHeader}</h2>
            <p>{location.state.uploadSuccess ? successBody : failureBody}</p>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Submission;
```

and:

```
const server = http.createServer();
const wsServer = new WebSocket.Server({ server });
const connectedClients = {};

wsServer.on('connection', async (ws, req) => {
    // Extract the client ID from the URL query parameters
    const clientId = req.url.slice(1);

    // Associate the client ID with the WebSocket connection
    ws.id = clientId;

    // Store the WebSocket connection in the connectedSockets object
    connectedClients[clientId] = ws;

    // Handle incoming messages from the client
    ws.on('message', async (message) => {

        console.log(`Received message from ${clientId}: ${message}`);
        console.log(Object.keys(connectedClients))
            // When client connects check if job is finished
        if (fs.existsSync(`output/${clientId}_results.csv`)) {
            const resultPath = path.join(__dirname, 'output', `${clientId}_results.csv`);
            const output = [];
            await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                fs.createReadStream(resultPath)  
                    .pipe(parse({ delimiter: ",", from_line: 2 }))
                    .on("data", (row) => {output.push(row)})
                    .on('end', resolve)
                    .on('error', reject)
            })
            sendMessageToClient(clientId, JSON.stringify(output));
        }
    });
    ws.on('close', () => ws.close());
});
```

When the client connects, the socket is created successfully, but after around ten seconds, the following error occurs "Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:3001/ltnbajzc001jtyvyt73ss". After this, when the server sends a message to the client it does not respond. If I refresh the page, the client receives the message. How can I prevent the socket from dying as it appears to be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone finding this, I figured out the problem which was unrelated to the above. Particularly, in addition to this websocket server, I had a bull job queue running in the same process. When my client connected to the server, a job would be launched. Because these jobs were long running, they were blocking the event loop and thus the client was unable to connect to the websocket server. I solved this by launching the job in a separate process.